# JUnit - Parameterized Test - Stopping compiling

Tags: junit, parametrized-testing

Code that I writed below stopping compliling before contructor or @Before (depend of hiding). There is no errors and It can't run even one time.

I did it with tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm

Can somebody have idea what is wrong with this code?

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;



    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParametryzowaneTestyKarty {
        private ArrayList<Karta> talia;
        private String wynik;
        private karty kartyy;

       @Before
       public void initialize() { 
            kartyy = new karty();
       }

       public ParametryzowaneTestyKarty(ArrayList<Karta> talia, String wynik) {
          this.talia = talia;
          this.wynik = wynik;
       }

       @Parameterized.Parameters
       public static Collection wyniki() throws FileNotFoundException {
           
           File plik22 = new File("...");
           Scanner test = new Scanner(plik22);
           
           while(test.hasNextLine()) { 
                ArrayList<Karta> talia = new ArrayList<>();
                String wiersz = test.nextLine();
           
               String[] parts = wiersz.split(",");
                for(int i=0;i<10;i+=2) {
                    String part0 = parts[i]; 
                    String part1 = parts[i+1];
                    int kol=Integer.parseInt(part0); 
                    int fig=Integer.parseInt(part1);
                    Kolor[] k = Kolor.values();
                    Kolor ko=k[kol];
                    Figura[] f = Figura.values();
                    Figura fi = f[fig];
                    talia.add(new  Karta(ko, fi));
                    String w = parts[10];
                    
                    Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                         { talia, w },
                      });
                }
           } 
          return Arrays.asList();     
       } 
       @Test
       public void TestParametryzowaneKarty() {
           System.out.println("1");
          System.out.println("Karty : " + talia);
          assertEquals(wynik, 
          karty.check(talia));
}   
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know the exact error you are getting.

There are some issues with your code, as `Arrays.asList()` doesn't do what you are expecting, and as thus the method `public static Collection wyniki()` is returning a empty list.

The following code might fix the issue, but I doubt it as the `talia` list is reused for each row in the file that is being read.

```
   @Parameterized.Parameters
   public static Collection wyniki() throws FileNotFoundException {
       
       File plik22 = new File("...");
       Scanner test = new Scanner(plik22);
       
       while(test.hasNextLine()) { 
            ArrayList<Karta> talia = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Object[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
            String wiersz = test.nextLine();
       
           String[] parts = wiersz.split(",");
            for(int i=0;i<10;i+=2) {
                String part0 = parts[i]; 
                String part1 = parts[i+1];
                int kol=Integer.parseInt(part0); 
                int fig=Integer.parseInt(part1);
                Kolor[] k = Kolor.values();
                Kolor ko=k[kol];
                Figura[] f = Figura.values();
                Figura fi = f[fig];
                talia.add(new  Karta(ko, fi));
                String w = parts[10];

                // new code
                rows.add(new Object[]{talia, w} );
            }
       } 
      return rows;     
   }
```

Comment: I had to get a few things out of the loop, but it works. Thank you!